# Select where: classification and its children

Tags: sql, oracle, query-performance, maximo, oracle18c

I have a query where I select workorders where the classification = 60280 or where the classification is a child of 60280:

```
select
    wo.*
from
    workorder wo
where
    exists (select 1 from classancestor where ((ancestor = '60280')) and (classstructureid=wo.classstructureid))
```

(For what it's worth, this is similar to how the [Advanced Search window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9lkDe.png) functions in the Maximo List View.)

While the query above does work fine, I suspect that it won't scale well on a large table, due to the subquery.

Is there a way to select a classification and its children without using a subquery?

Comment: you could rewrite it as a JOIN, but there's no guarantee that it will be more efficient. Oracle will create an execution plan based on the information you want.

Comment: I don't understand. In the word explanation you say something about "classification = xyz". I don't see anything like that in your WHERE condition. What am I missing?

Comment: OK - I see the edit you made. I still don't understand it. I see you are looking for ancestor = '60280'. I still don't see where you are looking for the rows where "classification" itself is '60280'. (I also don't see your table definitions, so I don't know what "classification" is - I suppose this is because the question is very specifically about **maximo**, which I haven't heard of.) In any case - it seems a hierarchical (CONNECT BY) query might be your best bet. But, you already have a "correct answer" so I guess you don't care anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select
    wo.*
from
    workorder wo join classancestor ca on (ca.classstructureid=wo.classstructureid)
where
    ca.ancestor = '60280'
```

But this is not necessarily better because Oracle will optimize as it sees fit. Try running it a couple of times to see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

I adapted @Mankowitz's answer:

```
select
    wo.*
from
    workorder wo 
left join 
    classancestor ca 
    on ca.classstructureid = wo.classstructureid
where
    ca.ancestor = '60280'
 
    and woclass in ('WORKORDER', 'ACTIVITY') 
    and historyflag = 0 
    and istask = 0
```